# How do I create a .deb package so that a specific file is not overwritten when updated?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, debian

I have a server. I need to package it in a * .deb package. The file folder contains the .env file, which contains the configs for starting this server (the user can change the configs after installation). How to make sure that when updating with the same * .deb package, this .env file is not overwritten?

Comment: This is much too vague to accommodate a useful answer. If you have configuration files, you declare them as `conffile`, which superficially does what you are asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debian packaging: how to update an earlier version of a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456862/debian-packaging-how-to-update-an-earlier-version-of-a-package)